# Что делает буква "J" в JButton?

Tags: java

Что делает буква "J" в `javax.swing.JButton`?
Взято [отсюда](http://www.brian-borowski.com/software/puzzle/GUI.java).

Comment: Буква J в имени JButton? Это имя класса, разработчики придумали такое, видимо J означает Java ... Она ничего не делает, это как спрашивать, что делает буква А в вашем имени

Comment: [Подобный вопрос на enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/665239).

Comment: это лучший вопрос, который я видел

Answer (score 1):

Эм... Вопрос немного... кхм... странный. Это просто название классов. Когда разрабатывали *Swing*, разработчики придумали "особенность" названия всех Swing-компонентов и начали их называть с приставкой `J`.